# Is it possible to restrict fields on included associations with ActiveModelSerializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rails-api

The guide for the latest version (0.10.7) documents a `include` option, that restricts what associated serializers' data will be included in the json output, and a `fields` option, that restricts what attributes of the top level serializer will be included, but is there a way to restrict what fields on the associated serializer are included? This seems to be all or nothing.

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1849) includes the following example syntax that seemingly does exactly what I want, but it doesn't seem to work with the latest version:

`render json: @blog, include: 'posts.category, posts.author.address', fields: { posts: { category: [:name], author: [:id, :name] } }`